# Running check on empty input type of text

Tags: javascript, jquery

How would I run a check after a keypress function to see if an inputs value was empty so I can do another action.

For example.

```
    $("input[name=amount]").keypress(function() {
        $("table[name=apply]").show();
    });
```

I want to hide the table if the user deletes all the keystrokes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$("input[name=amount]").keyup(function() {
    if (this.value == '') {
        $("table[name=apply]").hide();
    } else {
        $("table[name=apply]").show();
    }
});
```

You will probably want to use either the `keyup` or `change` event so the value of the text-box has changed before the event handler runs. The `keypress` event fires before the value of the input has changed, so for instance if the input is blank and a key is entered, the value in the event handler would still read as blank.

Here is a demo: http://jsfiddle.net/jasper/C5KPq/

Answer (score 1):

You can try this using `keyup` event instead of `keypress` because `keypress` will not give you the latest value.

```
$("input[name=amount]").keyup(function() {
     //Here this points to the textbox element and value gives its content
     if(this.value == ''){
          $("table[name=apply]").show();
     }
});
```

If you want to toggle the table the you can use this.

```
$("input[name=amount]").keyup(function() {
     $("table[name=apply]").toggle(this.value != '');
});
```

[toggle(showOrHide)](http://api.jquery.com/toggle/) - Display or hide the matched elements.

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/KAYax/)**

Answer (score 1):

Use the `keyup()` method to perform the check after the keystroke has finished:

```
$("input[name=amount]").keyup(function() {
    if(this.value === ''){....}
});
```

If you bind to the `keypress` or `keydown` events, the value of the input inside your event handler will not yet have been affected by the keystroke. This is why you need to bind to `keyup` instead.

Answer (score 0):

you can use the following

```
if( $(this).val() == "")
```

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
if ($("input[name=amount]").val() == '') // input is empty
```